# What is the significance of the float festival - Theppotsavam?

Tags: scripture, temple, festivals, tirupati

I came across a few [videos](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=a3hhKEIbRLU) of Theppotsavam, a festival celebrated in some temples of South India. The principal murti is decorated and floated on a nearby river or lake. As per [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theppotsavam) it seems that it is celebrated in month of Chitthirai

So was wondering why is the procession carried out in such a manner ?

Comment: தெப்பம் (Theppam) = boat. Chitthirai is Vasantha ruthu (spring). Flowers bloom, water from winter would have melted from mountain tops and filled lakes. There are several utsavs arranged by rishis, by kings, by people etc. It is a time for Bhagavan and Devis to enjoy nature (like picnic) and bhaktas to enjoy the divinity. I couldn't find scriptural reference to it. Many of reasons behind daily activities and religious rituals are available in Tamil (or other regional) religious weeklies. Better if we start learning or atleast teaching next generation local languages.